# Inject Typed HttpClient in a class with other parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have this class in a Worker Service application,he's constructed with 2 string parameters that need to be injected, so that can't be registered as services:

```
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, HttpClient client, string username, string password)
{
    this._logger = logger;
    this._client = client;
    this.Username = username;
    this.Password = password;
}
```

and i defined this builder:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureServices((c, s) =>
        {
            s.AddHttpClient<MyService>(client => { 
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.myserviceurl.com"); 
            });
            s.AddTransient<IMyService>(sp => new MyService(
                sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyService>>(),
                sp.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>(),
                "username", 
                "password"
            ));
        });
```

but the HttpClient injected via IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService() isn't the same i added in the IServiceCollection with the AddHttpClient() method because the BaseAddress (and other defaultHeaders i omitted for brevity) is empty

Instead, if i remove the other 2 string parameters from the constructor and let the IServiceProvider to resolve the dependency i get the correct instance of the HttpClient

I definitely may not have understood how GetRequiredService works and I am still learning well how the IServiceProvider works, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Edit:

Also I found that if I use named client instead of typed client

```
s.AddHttpClient("MyService",client => { 
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.myserviceurl.com"); 
            });
```

and I resolve the dependency via:

```
s.AddTransient<IMyService>(sp => new MyService(
                sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyService>>(),
                sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("MyService"),
                "username", 
                "password"
            ));
```

Everything work as expected. What's the difference from Typed HttpClient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this overload of `AddHttpClient`:

```
builder.ConfigureServices((c, s) =>
{
    s.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>((client, sp) =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.myserviceurl.com");

        return new MyService(
            sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyService>>(),
            client,
            "username",
            "password"
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get that it cannot inject System.String.
It seems that if I use GetRequiredService<HttpClient>() with this definition of AddHttpClient, it will try to recreate the MyService constructor from 0, so it won't be able to inject username, password string parameters.

Comment: Why use `GetRequiredService<HttpClient>()`? The reason you define a typed http client is so that you don't have to inject `HttpClient` to your services. You inject `IMyService` instead.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in initializing it, so AddHttpClient completely replace AddTransient with this constructor?

Comment: Yes, it replaces AddTransient

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Don't use this

```
s.AddTransient<IMyService>(sp => new MyService(
                sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyService>>(),
                sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("MyService"),
                "username", 
                "password"
            ));
```

Just inject username or password from another class. Or set the values in `Configuration` and set it in the constructor.

option 1:

```
s.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>(); //I'm omitting code to set up http client
```

Then in the constructor

```
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, HttpClient client, IConfiguration config)
{
    this._logger = logger;
    this._client = client;
    this.Username = config["username"]; //set in user secrets see below
    this.Password = config["password"]; //set in user secrets see below
}
```

or option 2

```
//create a credentials singleton class and inject that in MyService
s.AddSingleton<CredentialsClass>(new CredentialsClass("username","password"));
s.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();// I'm omiting code for http client
```

Then in the constructor

```
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, HttpClient client, CredentialsClass creds)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
        this._client = client;
        //creds.UserName and creds.Password
    }
```

Also: Never had code creds. Use [UserSecrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows) instead on local development.

Comment: Currently the credentials come from a configuration file instantiated just with IOption, what I do is cycle these configurations and instantiate the various objects.

How should I do in this case to instantiate multiple MyService type objects with different parameters?
what im actually doing is something like this: options.MyService.ForEach(p => s.AddTransient<IMyService>(m => new MyService(...., p.Username, p.Password)));
So in the Worker i have and IEnumerable<IMyService> injected

Comment: So the creds change based on the situation? I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe you can edit your question?

Comment: No, i instantiate multiple object of the same type with different parameter

Comment: What's the criteria for using a different parameter?

Comment: they are just different credentials. It's a background worker that make query to an API endpoint with different credentials and parse the output. Each credentials gives a different output.

Comment: in that case have the background worker set the credentials before making the request based on the query without injecting them. Just call something like .SetCreds(username, password);